# What is the C# equivalent of Java's Instant.now()?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

When using [`Instant.now()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#now--) in Java one gets 2019-01-21T05:47:26.853Z.

Which function is available in C# that returns an identically formatted date and time? If that is not available: How can one get the same output in C#?

Comment: What is `Instant.now()`? Is that supposed to be C# or .NET? Why is `DateTime.Now` not sufficient?

Comment: `DateTime.Now` or `DateTime.UtcNow`

Comment: https://nodatime.org/ , if you want a .Net implementation of `Instant`, to instnatiate, `Instant now = SystemClock.Instance.GetCurrentInstant();`

Comment: NodaTime is the equivalent of JodaTime. .NET itself uses the DateTime,DateOnly,TimeOnly, DateTimeOffset classes. All of these are binary values and have no format. In all cases values can be formatted as strings the same way as any other type, by using `ToString()`, `String.Format()` or a format string in a serializer. What you posted is the ISO8601 format, specified through the [standard `"o"` specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#the-round-trip-o-o-format-specifier), eg `DateTime.Now.ToString("o")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have a date in a special format, use `ToString()`.see this link [C# DateTime Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#the-round-trip-o-o-format-specifier)

```
  Console.Write( DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ"));
  //2023-02-28T14:58:26.055Z
```

Comment: It's better to link to the actual docs. [There's a standard specifier for the ISO8601 format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#the-round-trip-o-o-format-specifier), `"o"`

Comment: In certain cases (string Interpolation)you can remove the `ToString()` part and use only `DateTime.Now:yyyy`

Comment: @SH4NNY1 those circumstances sound like you specifying the wrong format.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the documentation for the `DateTime.Now` property.

Comment: `DateTime.Now` is not a constant.

Comment: I am unsure whether this constitutes an answer to the question.

Comment: @Jodrell Lol. Well, it's all a matter of perspective. Don't we live in an ever-lasting (well, not-quite-ever, but we tend to suppress that thought) present and everything just rushes past us? Reminds me of Einstein in a train crossing the Alps, asking the conductor: "Excuse me, does Lugano stop at this train?"

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica, you could argue that the thermodynamic arrow is an illusion and all events are just vectors in n-dimensional spacetime. Time is just one of the axes on which we perceive the transition between moments. Then we have more philosophical arguments without answer. However, the clock has changed over the time it took to read this comment.

Comment: I am sorry for my wording. I should have used the word "Property" and not a constant.